# If $n>1$ is an integer and $0<x\le n$ and $0<y\le n$, Prove that the equation $x^n+y^n=z^n$ has no solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n>1$ is an integer and $0<x\le n$ and $0<y\le n$, Prove that the equation $x^n+y^n=z^n$ has no solution.
My work:
This is obvious for integers by Fermat's Last Theorem. I also think that this holds for irrational numbers but I have no formal proof. I have got no clue how to approach this problem. Please help.

Comment: Seems to be having some problem with the question I guess

Comment: Intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 3):

Why would this not hold for irrational numbers? $$1^2 + 1^2 = (\sqrt 2)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Not true if you allow real numbers, as you seem to be doing. Tak $n=2$, $x=y=1$ and $z=\sqrt{2}$.